# Good Follow-Up Campaigns for Master of The Fallen Fortress

Tags: pathfinder-1e, game-recommendation, published-adventures, pathfinder-society

I'm a newbie GM about to run Master of The Fallen Fortress for a group of equally newbie players. If they get excited about Tabletop RPG's and want to continue playing, what would be a good campaign to continue with? I'm looking for something related to the Pathfinder Society.